# Expected comma before

Tags: c++

I am writing a win32 GUI program that has a button and I am getting an error. I have followed a tutorial exactly as far as I can tell.

```
error: expected primary-expression before ',' token|
```

My source code:

```
button=CreateWindow ("BUTTON",
                            "This is a button",
                            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                            20, 50, 200, 20,
                            HWND, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Regarding [your recent edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35640727/3), you needn't update your _Question_ with information on how to solve it; rather, you should [_Accept_ the answer that best solved your problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (which is presumably [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35640733/4143855))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HWND` should be a type name. You will have to put a name of declared variable or some value there instead of the type name.

Comment: Rather, although it _is_ a type, it should not be.

Comment: Thank you. hwnd in lower case appears to work.